# MS SQL - Problem selecting a subset of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I'm having a SQL brainfart moment. I am trying to get a set of records when any of the attribute IDs for that product is a certain value.

Problem is, I need to get all other attributes for that same product along with it.

Here's an illustration for what I mean:
[image]

Is there a way to do that? Currently I am doing this

```
select product_id
from mytable
where product_attribute_id = 154
```

But I obviously only get the single record:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My SQL skills are a bit basic.

**EDIT**

There's one condition I forgot to mention. There are times where I need to be able to filter on two attribute IDs. For example, in the first image above, the lower set (product ID 31039) has attribute id 395. I would need to filter on 154, 395. The result would not include the top set (31046) which does not have an attribute id 395.

Comment: Doesn't make sense why you would only get one record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT * myTable where Product_Id IN (SELECT Product_Id FROM MyTable WHERE Product_AttributeID = @parameterValue)
```

In English: Get me all the records such that their product id is in the set of all product ids such that their attribute id is equal to @parameterValue.

EDIT:

```
SELECT * myTable where Product_Id IN (SELECT Product_Id FROM MyTable WHERE Product_AttributeID = @parameterValue1) AND Product_Id IN (SELECT Product_Id FROM MyTable WHERE Product_AttributeID = @parameterValue2)
```

That should do it.

Comment: This is definitely on the right track. Thanks! I added an edit (sorry!) with the need to filter on an additional attribute ID. Would I just need an OR statement on the inner query?

Comment: (re my last comment) And actually I couldn't use an or, because I only need records where both of the attribute IDs are found.

Comment: So, by the edit, you mean that there must exist two records for the product_id to be in the set, one with value A and one with value b?

Comment: @jyoseph: The inner query would then look something like `(SELECT Product_Id FROM MyTable WHERE Product_AttributeID IN (154,395) GROUP BY Product_Id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product_AttributeID) = 2)`

Comment: @Chris: The `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product_AttributeID) = 2` portion of my query means that BOTH must match.

Comment: Right on! I think this is going to work. So with the `= 2`, the 2 signifies how many attribute IDs correct?

Comment: much appreciated guys. I love you.

Comment: Just a heads up, still referring back to this answer to this day, 4 years later.

Answer (score 4):

Using proper joins, you can link back to the same table

```
select B.*
from mytable A
-- retrieve B records from A record link
inner join mytable B on B.product_id = A.product_id
where A.product_attribute_id = 154  -- all the A records
```

EDIT: to get products that have 2 attributes, you can join another time

```
select C.*
from mytable A
-- retrieve B records from A record link
inner join mytable B on B.product_id = A.product_id
inner join mytable C on C.product_id = A.product_id
where A.product_attribute_id = 154  -- has attrib 1
  AND B.product_attribute_id = 313  -- has attrib 2
```

Comment: +1 This is awesome, going to try to wrap my head around this. It's partially working but there are some other antics causing problems.